# EC2 (Linux) cannot find TA-Lib headers even though I have installed the binaries - any ideas how to fix?

Tags: python, linux, amazon-ec2, ta-lib

I installed the binaries of TA-Lib into an EC2 instance with:

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/ta-lib/ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
tar -xzf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz
cd ta-lib/
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

As per documentation.

But running `pip install TA-Lib` fails with:

```
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/include -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/homebrew/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/ta-lib/include -I/tmp/pip-build-env-sib_bev3/normal/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.17/x64/include/python3.9 -c talib/_ta_lib.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/talib/_ta_lib.o
      talib/_ta_lib.c:747:10: fatal error: ta-lib/ta_defs.h: No such file or directory
        747 | #include "ta-lib/ta_defs.h"
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
```

I confirmed ta-lib files are indeed inside `/user/include`, which is one of the places gcc claims to be searching for it.

I also tried passing in options to pip, like so:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-L/usr/include/ta-lib/lib" --global-option="-I/usr/include/ta-lib/include" --install-option="--prefix='/usr/include/ta-lib/'"
```

Any ideas of what else I can try?

Thank you!